# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error to acess panel WordPress when i change to SSL (https)

Tags: wordpress, https

I change my website to SSL/HTTPS, but when I open panel I see this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error.
I didin't change the .htaccess, because when I change I see the same error in public website

Comment: What do `curl -i http://yourwebsite` and `curl -i https://yourwebsite` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G'day.

This can be caused by a number of things, but usually people get it when they configure apache to force https without changing the wordpress configuration in settings->general.

If you have done this, you can hardcode the values in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

..and then change your home url in settings->general

Changing to https is safest when you replace all occurrences in the database. You can do this via a plugin (such as https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/) or by doing a find/replace on the export/import of your database.

The same problem can occur in the opposite direction. ie: there may already be a hardcoded WP_HOME and/or WP_SITEURL defined in your wp-config.php

You will have success when all your ducks are in a row:

- .htaccess
- apache config (or web.config if windows)
- wp-config.php
- wp-admin/settings/options-general.php

Here's a reference article:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/

EDIT: additinal info in reply to your response:

It sounds like you need to check the redirects in your apache config:

    `RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com.br [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]`

If your webserver config (or .htaccess) conflicts with your wordpress config, you will get the loop. you need to be canonical regarding www.example.com.br vs example.com.br
Posts guid is not the only place where you will find reference. You need to change post_exerpt and post_content.
The replace statement helps but not always - you might find that plugins have escaped stuff so your replace would be http://example.com

Finally, there are plugins and themes such as Avada that write cache files and dynamic css files to your wp-content folder which may also conflict with your config. Make sure all caches are cleared and review your plugins and theme.

Comment: I make this, but the problem continue. I always change the url by settings->general and run the query:

Comment: `UPDATE mc_posts
SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://mysite.com.br', 'https://mysite.com.br')`; 
----------For all table, like mc_options, mc_posts, mc_posts, mc_postmeta, mc_postmeta

Comment: But the problem continue